# call function inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have written code like

```
class A {
    public String show (D obj) {
        return ("A and D");
    }
    public String show (A obj) {
        return ("A and A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public String show(B obj) {
        return ("B and B");
    }
    @Override
    public String show(A obj) {
        return ("B and A");
    }

}


class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        A ab = new B();
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(ab.show(b));
    }  
}
```

The outcome is B and A. I don't understand why it isn't B and B since b is a B object. But if I change
A ab = new B() to B ab = new B()
The outcome will be B and B. Why is that

Answer (score 0):

Since `ab` is `A`, it calls virtual `A.show`, but since `ab` is actually a `B`, the actual method called is `B`'s override of the original `A`'s virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler uses static binding with respect to the types of arguments passed as parameters.  This determines which *overload* is called, in the class of the type of the variable, here `A`.

The static type of `ab` is `A`, so the only method named `show` that matches is `show(A)`.

The JVM uses dynamic binding with respect to the runtime types of the objects on which methods are called.  This determines which *override* is called.  This is polymorphism.

The runtime type of `ab` is `B`.  There is an override of `show(A)` in `B`, so that is the method that is called, which prints "B and A".